# Suddenly cannot use GPU drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I had a series of simulations running on my machine. After many hours of normal work, suddenly I cannot use the GPUs anymore. I honestly don't know where to start looking for problems, as I did not touch the machine since then.

Running `nvidia-smi` results in the error:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

The fact is that I have the driver installed and I was using them until the night before (everything just stopped working during the night). I've tried to simply reboot the machine but it didn't help. Any idea of what I could check?

---

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Running `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` results in:

```
17:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
17:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
--
65:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [TITAN Xp] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [TITAN Xp]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
65:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Thank you,
G.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command. Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: My 18.04 machine got an Nvidia driver update yesterday. Perhaps that update caused your issue.

Comment: @OrganicMarble this is really scary. How do I check if my drivers have been updated, too?

Comment: You can look in /var/log/apt/ for the logfiles. If you do not have automatic updates enabled, it is likely not the cause.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm afraid you were right! By checking the file ```/var/log/apt/history.log``` I found: ```Start-Date: 2020-06-26  06:30:51
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libnvidia-common-440:amd64 (440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2, 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-06-26  06:30:51```.  Is this the update you were referring to? How can I go back to the old version of the drivers and disable automatic upgrades for the future? Thank you a lot for spotting this! :)

Comment: That is the update I was talking about. I also use the 440 driver. Before trying to revert (which is a problematic job) make sure the update is fully completed and reboot. `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` then a reboot. I had a *lot* more packages than that installed which makes me think your unattended-upgrades may only install security updates and only that one package was marked that way.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and, as you say, there were more packages to install, some of which with "nvidia" in the name. Unfortunately, after upgrading and rebooting the machine, I still cannot run nvidia-smi (same error)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109924/discussion-between-gab-and-organic-marble).