# nvidia driver 440.100 broke communication with GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu

I cannot use the GPUs anymore since the last update of Nvidia drivers. I have **Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**.

By checking the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file, I found:

```
Start-Date: 2020-06-26  
06:30:51 Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade 
Upgrade: libnvidia-common-440:amd64 (440.82-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.2, 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) 
End-Date: 2020-06-26  06:30:51
```

As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254253/suddenly-cannot-use-gpu-drivers?noredirect=1#comment2118869_1254253), I've tried `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade` and rebooted the machine. Unfortunately, this did not help.

Running `nvidia-smi` gives me:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Running `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` results in:

```
17:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
17:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
--
65:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [TITAN Xp] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [TITAN Xp]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
65:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

If I run python and:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.get_visible_devices()
```

I have the error:

```
2020-06-27 17:39:04.117940: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2020-06-27 17:39:04.117989: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (imt_deep): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you, G.

---

**Edit:**

The output of `uname -a` is:

```
Linux imt_deep 4.19.0-041900-generic #201810221809 SMP Mon Oct 22 22:11:45 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How did You install nvidia driver ? What is Your current kernel `uname -a` ? Looks like Your nvidia driver has not been properly installed. One way is to uninstall (purge) all nvidia related packages and install only the latest ones `440.100.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz thanks for the help. I will add the output of `uname-a` to the question. I haven't installed the Nvidia drivers in person, but I think it was installed using **apt-get**. Is there a way of checking this?

Comment: Unattended Upgrades work on apt so You should be able to use apt to purge nvidia drivers and related libs.

Comment: Wo you would suggest to remove the current drivers and then install the old drivers from zero? Could you be more explicit, please? :) I'm not very familiar with these things...

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Just posted in a [thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded-ubuntu-18-10/70495/97?u=mbarstead) over on the NVIDIA-side of the equation. Problems seem to be coinciding with [release date](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/160175/en-us) of the most recent drivers but still unclear what the root cause is to me at least.

Comment: does the hdmi from nvidia card -> monitor works?

Comment: if not you messed up with linux kernel headers.